# Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\le x}\frac 1n$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n\le x}\frac 1n=\log (x+2)+O(1)$.

We have, $\displaystyle \sum_{n\le x}\frac 1n=\log x +\gamma+O(1/x)$. Now if I can show that $\log(x+2)-\log x+O(1/x)=O(1)$ then I have done.

Now, $\log(x+2)-\log x+O(1/x)=\log \left(\frac{x+2}{x}\right)+O(1/x)=O(1/x).$

How can I prove this ?

Comment: I don't understand the thing in yellow. I've never seen all big Os in an equation

Comment: @mathworker21 Fixed.

Comment: Also, you don't need the $O(1)$ if you have the $O(\log (x+2))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is
$\log(1+z) < z$ 
for $z > 0$.

Then
$\log(x+2)-\log(x)
=\log(1+\frac{2}{x})
\lt \frac{2}{x}
=O(\frac1{x})
$.

To show
$\log(1+z) < z$ 
for $z > 0$:

$\log(1+z)
=\int_0^z \frac{dt}{1+t}
\lt \int_0^z dt
=z
$.

You can also use the integral
to get a lower bound:

$\begin{array}\\
\log(1+z)
&=\int_0^z \frac{dt}{1+t}\\
&\gt \int_0^z \frac{dt}{1+z}\\
&=\frac{z}{1+z}\\
&=\frac{z+z^2-z^2}{1+z}\\
&=z-\frac{z^2}{1+z}\\
&\gt z-z^2\\
\end{array}
$