# Why is $\sum_{n \leq x }1/n=\log(x)+\mathcal{O(1)}$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I know I can compare  $\sum_{n \leq x}1/n$ with $\log(x).$ I also think $\log(x) \leq\sum_{n \leq x}1/n.$

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3051851/42969

Comment: @Martin R , thanks for the help