# Where does the Euler Mascheroni constant come from in the formula $\sum_{n≤x} 1/n= \log(x)+\gamma +O(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, euler-mascheroni-constant

From this question,

[Asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\le x}\frac 1n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051851/asymptotic-formula-for-sum-n-le-x-frac-1n)

The author claims without proof that this identity holds.

$$\sum_{n≤x} 1/n= \log(x)+\gamma +O(1/x) .$$

It is apparently well known enough, but I can't seem to figure out where the $\gamma$ would come from. Can someone provide a reference or help?

Comment: It is the definition of that constant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant Proving the convergence of $$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac 1 n -\log x$$ is a good problem (you should try it).

Comment: if we name $H_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$  then sequence $a_n = H_{n+1}  - \log n $  is decreasing   while sequence $b_n = H_n  - \log n $    is increasing. They crash into each other   at the same limit... This arrangement of sequences crashing into each other ( like trains going in opposite directions on the same tracks)   is used in French mathematics education,  some name resembling `adjacent sequences.'  Jean Marie thinks it may go back to Cauchy.... Note $a_n = b_n + \frac{1}{1+n} $

Comment: Your formula essentially *defines* $\gamma$. It is not hard to prove that $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}-\log x$ converges to a constant as $x\to\infty$, but its "elementary closed-form" is not known (and is expected not to exist in some sense). So people simply decided to denote this constant by $\gamma$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391704/what-are-suites-adjacentes-called-in-english

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551025).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)$,

we could have:
$$S_{n+1}-S_{n}= \frac{1}{n+1}-\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})$$

with a more trivial fact that $\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(1+x)$ when $x>0$, let$x=\frac{1}{n}$, then we could know $S_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence.

since $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n)>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}
 dx-\ln(n)=\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x}dx-\ln(n)=\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)>0$

we could know $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$ do exist by monotone convergence theorem.